# Is there a way to write the compiled javascript file on disk when using webpack-dev-server?

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server

Originally the webpack-dev-server save files on memory, i'd like to write the bundle to the disk.

Comment: may I ask you why do you need a dev server if you write the files to your disk? This is nearly the only advantage it has vs. any other server. Just use the watch mode instead?

Comment: See my answer bellow, i figure out that the watch option will help me. I need the files written on the disk for a Cordova project.

Answer (score 1):

Using `webpack -w` or `webpack --watch`, it will bundle the project and save on the disk on the 'dist' or 'build' folder (depends on your webpack configurations).

Click the link bellow to see the configuration options ('aggregateTimeout' and 'poll')

[(Configuration options)](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/watch/)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there's [a plugin](https://github.com/gajus/write-file-webpack-plugin) for what you want to do.